# How to call a parameterized constructor in ASP.NET Core with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have created an interface IConnection

```cs
public interface IConnection
{
    string GetString(int? value);
}
```

Created a service class connection and having the below constructor

```cs
public Connection(string connectionString)
{
}
```

Created a GetString method in Connection.cs

```cs
public string GetString(int? value)
{
}
```

In Startup.cs, I registered the dependency as

```
services.AddTransient<IConnection>(x =>
    new Connection(x.GetRequiredService<string>())
);
```

From controller I don't know how to invoke `GetString` method with parameterized constructor.
It is always taking the default constructor.
Please help me to resolve the same.

Thanks
Krishnan

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. The controller should get injected with an `IConnection` depndency in its constructor, and that would allow you to call `connection.GetString` from within one of its action methods. What is the problem is from perspective of the controller? From perspective of registering `Connection`, however, your registration is problematic. You are requesting a `string` from the container, but which `string` exactly? This is ambiguous. So what is it you are trying to achieve here and why wouldn't `AddTransient<IConnection>(x => new Connection("my constr"))` not work?

Comment: Yes like - AddTransient<IConnection>(x => new Connection("my constr")) is I am trying to achieve. But here I need dynamic string.

Comment: In that case, see [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Comment: Maybe using the `IOption` is the right thing for you: [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  
there is the `IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>` interface that could provide you the wanted behavior.